# R - gtrends: ISO language code "pt" ou "pt-BR" não funcionam?

Tags: r

. 
Pessoal, estou usando o gtrends e gostaria de obter o "related_topics" em português (de preferência o "pt-BR"), mas o argumento "hl" da função gtrends não está retornando para o português. Sem o argumento, ele retorna os tópicos relacionados em inglês. Alguém teria alguma dica? O código que estou utilizando é

```
gtrend1 <- gtrends("Futebol", 
      geo = "BR",
      hl = "pt-BR",
      time = "2018-04-28 2018-05-04")
```

Comment: Já tentou somente `"pt"` sem o `BR`?

Comment: tentei sim. Também não funcionou. Retorna como "NULL"

Comment: Não é `pt_BR`? Com `_`, não `-`.

Comment: Rui, grato pela sugestão, mas não é, não. Deu o erro: "hl %in% language_codes$code is not TRUE". Estou pensando que talvez seja alguma configuração do meu computador.

Comment: Comigo funciona, não dá qualquer erro. Já tentou fechar o R e reiniciar?

Comment: Que engraçado. O argumento `hl = "pt-BR"` também não funciona comigo. Na verdade, o único `hl` que funciona pra mim é `hl = "en"`, mas aí ele retorna os resultados apenas em inglês.

Comment: Confirmo o problema com hl = "pt-BR". Se eu vou no [trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=BR&q=futebol&hl=pt-BR), eu vejo o resultado em português. Mas quando baixo o arquivo csv, obtenho o mesmo resultado do gtrendsR.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que alguns usuários estão com problemas e outros (como eu) não.
Esta resposta não deve resolver o problema, serve só para mostrar qual o output que obtenho.

```
library(gtrendsR)

gtrend1 <- gtrends("Futebol", 
      geo = "BR",
      hl = "pt-BR",
      time = "2018-04-28 2018-05-04")

gtrend1
#$`interest_over_time`
#                 date hits keyword geo gprop category
#1 2018-04-28 01:00:00   65 Futebol  BR   web        0
#2 2018-04-29 01:00:00  100 Futebol  BR   web        0
#3 2018-04-30 01:00:00   43 Futebol  BR   web        0
#4 2018-05-01 01:00:00   55 Futebol  BR   web        0
#5 2018-05-02 01:00:00   58 Futebol  BR   web        0
#6 2018-05-03 01:00:00   48 Futebol  BR   web        0
#7 2018-05-04 01:00:00   43 Futebol  BR   web        0
#
#$interest_by_country
#NULL
#
#$interest_by_region
#NULL
#
#$interest_by_dma
#NULL
#
#$interest_by_city
#NULL
#
#$related_topics
#NULL
#
#$related_queries
#NULL
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "gtrends" "list"
```

Quando baixei o ficheiro `"multiTimeline.csv"` e o li deu isto:

```
fute <- read.csv("multiTimeline.csv", skip = 2)

str(fute)
#'data.frame':   52 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Semana           : Factor w/ 52 levels "2017-05-14","2017-05-21",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ futebol...Brasil.: int  53 55 51 61 64 63 58 61 69 68 ...

head(fute)
#      Semana futebol...Brasil.
#1 2017-05-14                53
#2 2017-05-21                55
#3 2017-05-28                51
#4 2017-06-04                61
#5 2017-06-11                64
#6 2017-06-18                63
```

**Edição.**

Seguindo o comentário do @r_rabbit tentei sem `hl = "pt-BR"` e alguns dos termos aparecem em inglês e outros em português. Segue o código e o conteúdo de `gtrend2$related_topics` em formato `dput`.

```
gtrend2 <- gtrends("Futebol", 
      geo = "BR",
      time = "2018-04-28 2018-05-04")

gtrend2$related_topics <-
structure(list(subject = c("100", "24", "7", "7", "6", "6", "4", 
"3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "+150%", "+70%", "+40%"), related_topics = c("top", "top", 
"top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", 
"top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", "top", 
"top", "rising", "rising", "rising"), value = c("Soccer", "Vivo", 
"Santos FC", "SÃ£o Paulo FC", "Player", "Footballer", "Futebol Interior", 
"Ball", "Association", "Botafogo de Futebol e Regatas", "Ball", 
"American football", "Team", "Football in Brazil", "Stadium", 
"Northeast Region, Brazil", "Santa Cruz Futebol Clube", "Campeonato Baiano", 
"Campeonato Paulista", "Brazil national football team", "FIFA", 
"FIFA", "Stadium", "Campeonato Baiano"), geo = c("BR", "BR", 
"BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", 
"BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR"
), keyword = c("Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", 
"Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", 
"Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", 
"Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", "Futebol", 
"Futebol"), category = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), reshapeLong = list(varying = structure(list(value = "top"), v.names = "value", times = "top"), 
    v.names = "value", idvar = "id", timevar = "related_topics"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Oi Rui. Na visualização que postou acima não aparece o "related_topics", que seria o elemento de interesse. Quando o chamo com o "pt-BR" pelo argumento "hl", ele aparece como NULL, quando o chamo sem o argumento, ele aparece corretamente com os termos em inglês. Para você apareceu em português os termos do "related_topics"? Grato pela ajuda, abç!

Comment: @r_rabbit Editei a resposta com o que faltava. Quanto ao `related_topics`, não sei porquê mas não copiei para a resposta. Quanto ao código sem `hl = "pt-BR"`, aqui vai só `gtrend2$related_topics`, completo é grande.